# Volley setRetryPolicy timeout is not working

Tags: android, network-programming, android-volley

I want to set my application timeout duration to 60s, which mean my apps will only dismiss the ProgressDialog if it's getting reply from server or it reach timeout without getting reply from the server.

Currently I'm working with Volley library on android so this is what I do :

```
private void loginOnline(final String user, final String pwd, final String login_url){
        final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Communicating with Server");
        pd.show();
        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put(KEY_USERNAME, user);
        params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pwd);
        final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_url, new JSONObject(params),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        try {
                            int msg = response.getInt("status");
                            sendMessage(msg);
                        }
                        catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                pd.dismiss();
                Log.d("D", "onErrorResponse: "+error.getMessage());
            }

        });
        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,0,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        queue.add(jsonObjReq);
    }
```

The problem is when I try to connect to my server, it shows in the log :

```
D/D: onErrorResponse: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.123.x.xxx (port 3000) after 60000ms: isConnected failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)
D/Volley: [1] Request.finish: 3072 ms: [ ] http://192.123.4.215:3000/login 0xdde27c7c NORMAL 1
```

my question is why does it stop to connecting to the server before it reach 60000ms.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it isn't just failing to connect to the host-  its failing to find a route to it.  That means it can never talk to the host.  As such, it returns immediately.  The retry policy is working, but it only applies if a connection is possible.  It would also end immediately if the server rejected the connection, or a few other conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!